# Expanding array (few times) using realloc - crashes

Tags: c

```
int Add_Edge_To_Vertex(int vertexFromId,int vertexToId){
    vertex vertexTo=vertices[vertexToId];
    if(vertexTo.edgesInArrLength == vertexTo.numOfEdgesIn){ //multiply this vertex arr of edges if needed
        vertices[vertexToId].edgesInArrLength = (vertices[vertexToId].edgesInArrLength)*2;
        tmpVertexEdges = (edge*)realloc((vertices[vertexToId].edges),(vertices[vertexToId].edgesInArrLength)*sizeof(edge));
        if(tmpVertexEdges != NULL) {
            vertices[vertexToId].edges = tmpVertexEdges;
        }
        else
        {
            free(tmpVertexEdges);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

typedef struct vertex
{
    char* name; //not unique
    int id; //unique
    edge* edges; //array  edges
    int outDegree;
    int edgesInArrLength;
    int numOfEdgesIn;
    double rank;
}vertex;
```

This is how I initialize a vertex-

```
vertex res={(char *)malloc(strlen(name)*sizeof(char)),verticesCount,(edge*)calloc(1, sizeof(edge)),0,1,0,1};
```

when edge is this struct-

```
typedef struct edge
{
    int fromVertexId;
    int toVertexId;
    double weight;
}edge;
```

when i try to double-up the vertex.edges array (lines 3-12), the program crashes at the realloc part with this error message-
*** glibc detected**  /home/froike/workspaceC/Page Ranking/Debug/Page Ranking: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000009711d0 **

Comment: If this is C++, why aren't you using `std::vector`s? If it's C, why are you casting the return of `realloc`?

Comment: You might be overwriting `edges` somewhere else and gets segmentation fault when _realloc_.

Comment: I added your 'edit' properly now. Please remove your 'answer'

Comment: this is for C. I tried without the casting - same problem. I Cast the return so I'd be able to replace the old "vertices[vertexToId].edges".  I don't think I overwrite edges since I use it only to double-it-up (like here) or to add another edge to this edges array

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're not initialising the `edges` pointer in `struct vertex` and so the `realloc` call is trying to reallocate an invalid pointer? But as you haven't given us all the code I can't be sure.